Why my trained t5-small model generate a mess after I saved and loaded the checkpoint?
I was distilling my student model (base model t5-small)  based on a fine-tuned T5-xxl. Here is the config
student_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(
    args.student_model_name_or_path,
    torch_dtype=torch.float32,
    device_map="auto",
    cache_dir=args.cache_dir,
    quantization_config=quantization_config,
)

I saved the trained model using
output_dir = f"checkpoint"
student_model.save_pretrained(output_dir)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)

But when I try to load the ckp using
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(args.model_path)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(
        "checkpoint"
        torch_dtype=torch.float32,
        device_map="auto",
        cache_dir=args.cache_dir,
        quantization_config=quantization_config
)

it said that "Some weights of the model checkpoint at checkpoints were not used when initializing T5ForConditionalGeneration: ..." and the outputs of the model are really a mess. I was trying to figure it out but have no clues now.
I thought it was the problem with the quant_method since I trained the model with "load_8_bits" but add quantization_config didn't help.
